# Swap Linked list objects

Tags: c++11, linked-list

Following code works for sorting of the list  (Peter,10) (John,32) (Mary,50) (Carol,31)
Ordered lists:
List 1: (Carol,31) (Carol,31) (John,32) (Mary,50) 
however the peter is lost and carol is getting repeated, please help to suggest where Iam going wrong. WHat do I need to change in the loop to get this correct

```
LinkedList& LinkedList::order() 
{ 
  int swapped; 
  Node *temp;
  Node *lptr = NULL; 
  temp=head;
  // Checking for empty list 
  do
   { 
     swapped = 0    ; 
     current = head;                
     while (current->get_next() != lptr) 
     {
        if (current->get_data() > current->get_next()->get_data()) 
        {  
            temp->set_Node(current->get_data());
            current->set_Node(current->get_next()->get_data());
            current->get_next()->set_Node(temp->get_data()); 
            swapped = 1; 
        } 
        current = current->get_next(); 
      } 
      lptr = current;
  } 
  while (swapped); 
  return *this;
```

}

Comment: On the first pass through the outer loop, the inner loop is executed until `current2` becomes NULL.  The second and subsequent passes are no-ops, as `current2` is already NULL and the inner loop doesn't run.

Comment: All the assignments in the inner loop are to `*head` (`temp` is initially set equal to `head`, and never updated afterwards). Whatever value was originally stored in the head node is lost in the process (note how, in your example, `(Peter,10)` value is no longer present in the resulting list).

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I have revised the code and posted it here. now the following list List 1: (Peter,10) (John,32) (Mary,50) (Carol,31) upon sorting is shown as  List 1: (Carol,31) (Carol,31) (John,32) (Mary,50)

Comment: `temp` is still never updated and always points to `head`. `temp->set_Node(current->get_data())` still overwrites the contents of head node.

Comment: Thanks Igor, for pointing the issue, I changed the temp declaration to Node *temp= new Node();  it works now